# Excel web access chart losing formatting

Tags: 2013, excel, excel-web-access-webpart

A user has created a document in excel (works in 2007 and above). This document contains some simple data in one sheet and a chart in the other.

The problem is the chart which displays fine in excel, loses the formatting when displayed in the web part. In this case the data is meant to be a percentage but appears to be displaying as a general number.

All the formatting in the document itself (for both the graph and the data) has been set to percentage but the problem persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be a better idea to ask Office/Office Online forums of this one. SharePoint doesn't really do anything to the document.

Comment: Fair comment but it works in the office suite and Excel online. The only location it is not working is when the document is displayed via the web part in SharePoint. The question was focused on this and whether it was a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware this got down voted but in case anyone has a similar issue:

To fix our issue the data in the spreadsheet had to be set to 2 decimal places e.g. 10.50%, the web part for whatever reason would not accept 1 decimal place for example the format the user wanted was 10.5%.